# find out the records - first two date records of each member of every year- db2udb

Tags: sql, db2

Need Help -
Scenario - I have a table testdata with columns

```
memberid (varchar) ,codetype(varchar),effectivedate(datetime)
```

this table having 20k records - from year 2015 to 2021
I need to find out the records - first two date records of each member of every year [ only memberid is unique)
eg.

| member id | codetype | effectivedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 1/2/2015 |
| 123 | ABC | 1/2/2015 |
| 123 | ABC | 8/15/2015 |
| 123 | EFG | 9/15/2015 |
| 123 | EFG | 2/15/2018 |
| 345 | EFG | 3/14/2018 |
| 345 | EFG | 3/17/2018 |
| 345 | ABC | 9/19/2020 |
| 456 | EFG | 12/20/2021 |

result should be like below

| member id | codetype | effectivedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 1/2/2015 |
| 123 | ABC | 1/2/2015 |
| 123 | ABC | 2/15/2018 |
| 345 | EFG | 3/14/2018 |
| 345 | EFG | 3/17/2018 |
| 345 | ABC | 9/19/2020 |
| 456 | EFG | 12/20/2021 |

tried lot of ways but no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
with u as
(select memberid, codetype, effectivedate,
    row_number() over(partition by memberid, year(effectivedate) order by 
memberid) as rownum
from testdata)
(select memberid, codetype, effectivedate from u
where rownum <= 2)
```

Basically you get the row numbers of every record partitioned by memberid and the year of the record, then keep only the records where rownum is 1 or 2.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.. only change i made to your query is -- below with all code and that is what i want. thanks again-                    with u as
(select memberid, codetype, effectivedate,
    row_number() over(partition by memberid, year(effectivedate) order by 
memberid,codetype,effectivedate) as rownum
from testdata)
(select memberid, codetype, effectivedate from u
where rownum <= 2)

Comment: Glad it's working for you buddy ^^